# cannot navigate method definition scala code in inteliij

Tags: intellij-idea

I'm using Java and Scala on IntelliJ 2016 3.4 Ultimate on Mac.
I can navigate method declaration/implementation of Java.
But can't do it Scala code.

The way I'm doing in Java is if I `Command + hove over left mouse/trackpad` on a method, it displays some methods and if I click one of methods, I can go to that method.
( I don't hit `Command + shift` as described in [here][1]

[1]: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/navigating-to-declaration-or-type-declaration-of-a-symbol.html in Java code)

But cannot do navigate methods for Scala code by hitting `Command + hove over left mouse/trackpad` on a method.

I checked `Preference > Language & Frameworks > Scala` but couldn't find setting for this.

Do I need to set up somewhere for scala in intelliJ?

Answer (score 4):

Right click on **src** folder and set **Mark Directory as > Sources Root**

Comment: If I have many 'src' folders within my project, is there a way I can use 'Mark Directory as > Sources Root' in batch?